# Does it make sense to divide mathematical theorems into those susceptible to experimental conjecture and those that are not?

Tags: math-history, conjectures, philosophy

I read the following in a good book: ”let's start from zero", the authors are Vinicio Villani and Maurizio Berni (pisan mathematicians) but I don't know if the book is also marketed outside Italy.

> I don't think I'm exaggerating when I say that the shocking discovery of the existence of incommensurable segments gave a decisive impulse to the development of all mathematics, understood as a theoretical, hypothetical-deductive discipline. In fact, the validity of other theorems of classical geometry (starting from those of Thales and Pythagoras) can be empirically verified on a drawing through experimental measurements, albeit approximate. Instead, the question of the commensurability or incommensurability of two segments eluded us then, as it eludes us today and will elude us forever to every attempt at experimental verification, given the inevitable imprecision of every physical measurement"

When I first read it, in my mind I enthusiastically endorsed this statement.  But then I thought about it and I had some doubts.  The statement seemed to imply that there are two classes of theorems, the one whose truthfulness can be suggested by so-called experimental and numerical arguments (even if obviously without a demonstration we are always at zero), and those which are totally precluded by a such approach that can suggest conjectures. But does this make sense? Really "the theorem the root of 2 cannot be expressed as a ratio between integers" is in this sense qualitatively different from the Pythagorean theorem? It is true that I can set about constructing squares on right-angled triangles and make measurements that lead me to conjecture the validity of the theorem, but I can also patiently set about searching for two integers such that the square of their ratio is two, and after long labors conjecture that such a pair of integers does not exist.  All this if I didn't have an easy proof available but it's not the point here now. In short, the question is: does the division of mathematical theorems into two classes, those that can be conjectured experimentally and those that cannot, make sense?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by experimental conjecture please?  Do you mean tested experimentally? Things can only be disproved by an experiment or by finding a counter example.  Pythagoras' theorem could be disproved or statement square root of 2 is irrational could be shown false if a counter example was found when squared that made 2, but no type of maths theorem could be proved by experiment.  Only  by deductions from axioms and even then occasionally the axioms could be false...

Comment: When you quote a source, you should *always* give a citation. Title and author of the book is sufficient.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry but I still don't know the Stack Exchange netiquette well. I hang out here quite rarely. I edited.

Comment: @JohnHunter Actually no, I wouldn't know how to clarify a concept that I consider self-evident: measurements or certain numerical results can lead us to consider statements to be true and therefore to look for a proof. Furthermore it is obvious that no mathematical theorem should be considered proven with experiments, as I explicitly point out in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the alleged "shocking discovery of the existence of incommensurable segments gave a decisive impulse, etc.": this is a bit of a historical misconception; see e.g., [this answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/15784/604) (at history of science and math).

As far as the $\sqrt2$ example: this is similarly dubious, since there are constructive proofs of this by using lower bounds for $\sqrt2-\frac{p}{q}$ in terms of $\frac{C}{q^2}$ for a suitable universal $C$ (bigger than $\frac{1}{10}$, say).  This is something testable: take your favorite rational approximation and check that it falls short of being an exact representation by a specific amount.

On the other hand, set-theoretic paradoxes such as [Banach-Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) surely cannot be predicted empirically :-)  So I would conjecture that the borderline may have to do with whether a theorem can be proved in ZF or if it requires the axiom of choice.

In conclusion, when the author writes

> "I don't think I'm exaggerating when I say that the shocking discovery of the existence of incommensurable segments gave a decisive impulse to the development of all mathematics, understood as a theoretical, hypothetical-deductive discipline"

he is indeed exaggerating.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a mathematically definable division, but I would argue that almost all mathematical theorems can be conjectured experimentally.

Consider the [four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theoremhttps://), which can be tested experimentally and was for over 100 years before it was proven using computers. Even now there isn't a visual "proof" of the conjecture like you might have with the pythagorean theorem, and there is no polynomial time algorithm to check if a graph is 4-colorable.

Consider [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), an intuitive (and visualizable) statement about convex functions (having non-negative second derivative) in probability. You can "test" this with some convex functions and certain probability distributions, but the proof is rigorous and general.

Many theorems are conjectured because someone tested some examples and saw a pattern. Surely geometry is particularly conducive to visual intuition, but I think it would be unrealistic to say that any theorem couldn't be conjectured by experimentation.

**Edit.** Some comments have made the point that one can answer the question "does *x* exist" by experimentation, and for some problems (like the existence of an odd perfect number) the proof would be extremely simple once you find the *x* you're looking for. Note that the inverse of these statements can still be conjectured by experimentation, just not proven.

Comment: The four colour theorem could be disproved by finding a small enough graph that needed 5 colours, but couldn't be proved experimentally as there are infinite number of graphs to check.  Whether it has properly been proved relies on axioms and also in that case trusting that computer programs etc... have no mistakes in them

Comment: @JohnHunter I think the point is that the 4-color theorem can be tested to the same extent Thales or Pythagoras can be tested -- a lot of attempts and no counterexample found yet.

Comment: The number and type of quantifiers of the theorem make the distinction. Theorems with a single existential quantifier (ie. there exists an odd perfect number), if true, can be proved experimentally. Theorems with a single universal quantifier, if false, can be disproved experimentally (eg. all numbers are odd). Theorems with multiple alternating quantifiers can be neither proved nor disproved experimentally by just looking trough the solutions.

Comment: @user3257842 What you say is true when you are able to make exact measurements. Empirical evidence involves approximate measurements, as described in the book. When the measurements are approximate, the example or counterexample may only **appear** true but may actually be false.

Comment: @David K yes that sounds right, it's like Karl Poppers view that scientific theories can only be disproved, and that saying a theory (or maths statement) is true is really a belief system that is useful until, perhaps one day,  the statement is disproved

Comment: The rationality of $\sqrt{2}$  can be stated as: "There exists a pair of natural numbers $(a,b)$ such that $a^2/b^2 = 2$". If true, this could be proven experimentally by finding such a pair, ie. going trough all possible pairs $(a,b)$ until a satisfactory one is found. Unfortunately, it is false.

Comment: @user3257842 What if $\sqrt2=a/b$ for integers $a$ and $b$, but each of these integers has over $10^{100}$ non-zero digits? How would you go about verifying that $a^2/b^2 = 2$? We can't even write either of those numbers.

Comment: It can be proven experimentally by someone with an arbitrarily large amount of time and memory on their hands. Mathematicians always assume those as given. 

Lots of yet unproven conjectures are believed to be true because we've been unable to find them a counterexample, despite searching up to very high numbers. Ex. the Collatz conjecture (checked up to $2.95*10^{20}$), or the non-existence of an odd perfect number.

Comment: @Logan_Post Thank you for your detailed response. I appreciate you taking the time to share your perspective. However, I would like to clarify that my main point was not so much about the viewability of theorems, but rather about the distinction between theorems that can be conjectured experimentally and those that cannot (what about numerical approach on conjectures in R^4 or in C^2?). I wanted to explore whether this division makes sense. Can you cite the opinions and arguments of any mathematician or philosopher of science in this regard?